# Nancy show model data in view

Tags: c#, view, model, nancy

Hi I'm trying to show my data from a model to a view. now I'm hard coding this data for now but this is what I've got.

Model:

```
public class Table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Position { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set;}

    public int GamesPlayed { get; set; }
    public int GamesWon { get; set; }
    public int GamesDrawn { get; set; }
    public int GamesLost { get; set; }

    public int GoalsForward { get; set; }
    public int GoalsAgainst { get; set; }
    public int GoalDifference { get; set; }

    public int Points { get; set; }
}
```

So in my module, I create a new instance of my table model, then add the data I want to show, then return the model to the view.

```
public class LeaderboardModule : NancyModule
{
    public LeaderboardModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = _ =>
            {
                var model = new Table();

                model.Position = 1;
                model.User = "Paddy";

                model.GamesPlayed = 5;
                model.GamesWon = 3;
                model.GamesDrawn = 2;
                model.GamesLost = 0;

                model.GoalsForward = 100;
                model.GoalsAgainst = 20;
                model.GoalDifference = 80;

                model.Points = 11;

                return View["Leaderboard", model];
            };
    }
}
```

And on the view I have `@inherits` `Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<Data.Models.Table>`. I want to display the information in a table so I display the data using `<td>@Model.position</td>`. But nothing is showing can't figure out why. do I need to convert my model to a list?

```
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<Fifa.Leaderboard.Data.Models.Table>
@{
   Layout = "Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<table>
<tr>
<th>Position</th>
<th>User</th>
<th>Games Played</th>
<th>Won</th>
<th>Drawn</th>
<th>Lost</th>
<th>Goals Forward</th>
<th>Goals Against</th>
<th>Goal Difference</th>
<th>Points</th>
</tr>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Id; i++)
{
    <tr>
    <td>@Model.Position</td>
    <td>@Model.User</td>
    <td>@Model.GamesPlayed</td>
    <td>@Model.GamesWon</td>
    <td>@Model.GamesDrawn</td>
    <td>@Model.GamesLost</td>
    <td>@Model.GoalsForward</td>
    <td>@Model.GoalsAgainst</td>
    <td>@Model.GoalDifference</td>
    <td>@Model.Points</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: can you share all the view code?

Comment: I've added breakpoints to the view but they don't get hit?

Comment: what's the value of Model.Id?

Comment: It's working, I hadn't set a value for the id. what an idiot! thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `Model.Id` to something greater than 0 in the handler before returning the view.